# Flutter iOS Bluetooth Permission

Tags: ios, flutter, bluetooth

I already have the permission_handler package inside my project to request GPS permission, however I want to request permission for bluetooth on iOS as well as check if I already have the permission.
However there seems to be no option to request the bluetooth permission since it is not listed here https://pub.dev/documentation/permission_handler_platform_interface/latest/permission_handler_platform_interface/Permission-class.html#constants

How can I check and request iOS Bluetooth permission in Flutter?

Comment: try https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue

Comment: This does not help as we are already using a different bluetooth package for our project

Comment: The Bluetooth permission request is shown automatically the first time you attempt to use Core Bluetooth on iOS. You simply need to have a usage detail string in your info.plist. If the user denies permission then you will get a `.denied` state in the `didUpdateState` delegate method. You will need to look at the source for whatever flutter Bluetooth package you are using to see how it exposes this to your app.

Answer (score 0):

The [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package should be able to check the Bluetooth status in an iOS device. Due to [limitations](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#how-to-use), it can only check if the Bluetooth is active or not. What you can do here is to display a prompt for users to enable the Bluetooth if the app needs it to be active and the Bluetooth is currently not.

```dart
if (await Permission.bluetooth.isRestricted) {
  // Display a prompt/pop-up for the user to enable bluetooth on their device
}
```